# Output examples with html

Tags: jsdoc, jsdoc3

I am wanting to output examples which has HTML within it such as

```
* @example
*     <div ng-app="reportingBuilderApp">
*         <div ng-view></div>
*     </div>
```

But at the moment it renders it "safely" as HTML however I want it as text, at the moment I am needing to write the example as below (which is much more tedious and ugly in the actual JS)

```
* @example
*     &lt;div ng-app="reportingBuilderApp"&gt;
*         &lt;div ng-view&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
*     &lt;/div&gt;
```

Is there any way of sorting JSDoc to prevent the HTML from being output "safely" automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using version 3.3.0-alpha4, with the following test file:

```
/**
 * @example
 * <div ng-app="reportingBuilderApp">
 *     <div ng-view></div>
 * </div>
 */
function foo() {
}
```

I get an example that shows up correctly in the output of jsdoc.

As the name suggests, 3.3.0-alpha4 is still in alpha. To my knowledge there is no version previous to 3.3.0-alpha... which has the fix for this problem, and no workaround for it. The bug report that prompted the fix is [here](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/511).

Comment: But if you look within the JSDoc it won't output as text will it? On mine when I try this the example is actually rendered as html ...

Comment: sorry I have just realised you've mentioned 3.3.0 and I am on 3.2.0 perhaps there has been a change for the new "alpha" version then

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I said in the answer: "Using version 3.3.0-alpha4..." and "To my knowledge there is no version previous to 3.3.0-alpha...".

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get around this. You will need to use HTML escape code if you want to show the < and > symbols in the final HTML JSDoc pages.